# Как пропустить выполнение кода плагина?

Tags: modx

MODX Revolution 2.7.3-pl.

есть плагин, который отрабатывает на эти события:

1. case 'msOnCreateOrder'
2. case 'OnUserSave'

что нужно прописать в код, чтобы система игнорировала код плагин и просто продолжила свою работу?

путь такой: клиент собирает корзину, нажимает «Заказать», система идёт в плагин, плагин крэшится, система не продолжает работу, у клиента ничего не происходит на странице.

просто выключить плагин нельзя.

спасибо :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сразу после

> case 'msOnCreateOrder:'

и

> case 'OnUserSave':

(да или вообще в самом начале плагина) впишите

```
return true;
```

тем самым плагин вернет успешный результат, ни отработав ни разу.